# Moving file based on first few words in name

Tags: python

I want to move a file that I downloaded.

I have tried this.

```
shutil.move('/Users/dgoodwin/Downloads/metrics-lifetime-20190513.csv', '/Users/dgoodwin/OneDrive/metrics-lifetime.csv')
```

This works as long as the name doesn't change. I found after another download that there is the date at the end which changes everyday.

Here is the image of the files  I am working with. [Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BBi8.png)

I would like to just use the first part of the name "metrics-lifetime" to search for in my downloads but I can't find out how grab partial paths.

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to move only the latest file or all the files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use use the `glob` module

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
for file in files:
    shutil.move(file, destination_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will proceed to use folder hierarchy loading.
[This](https://qiita.com/suin/items/cdef17e447ceeff6e79d) is a Japanese homepage, but it is written here.

Comment: Links are great, but it would be even more helpful if you could summarize a possible way to correct the problem outlined in the question.